# Django Postgres Make Migration Error

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have just deployed some code onto a production server from my local. I have set up a postgres database with a django app. The issue is when I run:

```
$ python3 /usr/Apps/manage.py makemigrations
```

I get the below error

```
##################################################
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "api_neli_report" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ort"."price", "api_neli_report"."prediction" FROM "api_neli_
```

*api_neli_report* is a model I have set up that has not been migrated, as I can't migrate it without getting the error.

Any idea how to fix this one?

Also see model:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class SSALi_Report(models.Model):

    date = models.DateField()
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='NA')
    market = models.CharField(max_length=250,default='NA')

    price = models.FloatField()
    prediction = models.FloatField()



    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date) + " - " + str(self.ticker)

class NELi_Report(models.Model):

    date = models.DateField()
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='NA')
    market = models.CharField(max_length=250,default='NA')

    price = models.FloatField()
    prediction = models.FloatField()
```

**please note the model is working on my local**

Also see my resource model:

```
# Logic/resources.py

from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from api.models import SSALi_Report
from api.models import NELi_Report
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
class SSALi_Resource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset =  SSALi_Report.objects.all()
        print("#"*50)
        print(queryset)
        resource_name = 'SSALi_Report'
        authorization = Authorization()

class NELi_Resource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset =  NELi_Report.objects.all()
        print("#"*50)
        print(queryset)
        resource_name = 'NELi_Report'
```

table on my local

```
 Schema |            Name            | Type  |  Owner   
--------+----------------------------+-------+----------
 public | api_neli_report            | table | postgres
```

Comment: what version of PostgreSQL, Djnago, and Psycopg2 are you using ?

Comment: Django==2.0.4
PostgreSQL 9.6.6 Python =3.5
psycopg2==2.7.4
psycopg2-binary==2.7.4

Comment: can you also post the model aswell. Thanks

Comment: see updated post

Comment: Where is `api_neli_report ` model?

Comment: Api is the app and the table is call api_neli_report on my local

Comment: Can you add the database configuration, which engine are you using ?

Comment: It should be 
```
default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        '......' }
```

Comment: django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2

Comment: Please show the entire traceback. It looks like you have some code that is running `NELi_Report.objects....` when your code is loaded, before the management command runs.

Comment: Also, note that you should not normally run `makemigrations` in production. The usual approach is to make migrations once in development, commit the migrations to your repository, then run `migrate` in production.

Answer (score 0):

So the only way around it was to export the local database as SQL and import it into the production database. it's not how I wanted to do it but it got the job done.